# Is crescere the correct word meaning to to grow or cultivate?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check

I am creating a program that helps people learn a growth mindset and “grow” into what they want to become. Is *crescere* the correct word meaning to to grow or cultivate?

Comment: It is fine, one of the oldest of the christian legends from Bohemia begins "Crescente fide christiana..." (When the christian faith was growing...).

Answer (score 10):

I think *crescere* is an excellent word for growing, be it concrete or spiritual.
Check [its dictionary entry in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=cresco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
It can be used in sentences like "I grow to be a better person" and "the pumpkin grows".

If you want "I grow pumpkins", the word *crescere* is not suitable.
It is intransitive and the subject is the one to grow.
If you want something transitive, like "cultivate", I recommend *colere*.
Check [its entry in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=colo1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) to see a range of meanings.
In fact, the English "cultivate" comes from this very verb.

So, the person or thing growing *crescit* and the person or thing that helps something grow *colit*.
The choice of words and especially forms depends on how you want to use these words.
If you want to ask about sentences or short phrases using these words, I recommend asking a new question focusing on syntax.